# how to filter for issues under several epics

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I would like to search for tasks located under several epics. 
All the epics have a unique suffix "Version 12", but I can't filter with wildcards.
What I thought of was to create a complicated filter but it also doesn't work. Here's how it looks:

issuetype = "Task" and "Epic Name" in (issuetype = epic AND fixVersion = "Version 12.0")

any ideas how to solve this??

Comment: Do you have script-runner ?

Comment: I don't think so... is it a paid add-on?

Comment: Yes it is paid. If you do have it then you will find the solution for this in their documentation